# Erlang: Child process execute normally until received "die"?

Tags: concurrency, erlang

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a child process continue normal operation until it receives a "die" message from a parent process.

Here's the child process's code.

```
-module(sensor).
-export([start/1]).     % must also export function that will be spawned


%%  create second thread, pass self() as argument so it knows how to reply
%%  exchange messages with second thread until sum=0
start(SlaveNr) ->
    %this part is not right. It waits for die and does nothing else
    receive
        die ->
            io:format("slave ~p: received die~n", [SlaveNr])
    end,
    random:seed(now()),
    Measurement = random:uniform(11),
    if Measurement == 11 ->
        exit(crash);
    true->
        io:fwrite("slave ~p Random # ~p~n",[SlaveNr, Measurement])
    end,
    Sleep_time = random:uniform(10000),
    timer:sleep(Sleep_time),
    start(SlaveNr).
```

As you can see, it's not executing normally. It's just waiting until it receives a die message. So how can I have it execute its normal function until it receives a die from the parent indicating all child processes should exit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to check the mailbox at each loop, you can achieve this by adding a timout of 0 ms. So the process will check if any received message match to die, if not it will immediately continue.

```
receive
        die ->
            io:format("slave ~p: received die~n", [SlaveNr])
        after 0 ->
            ok
    end,
```

It is always possible to stop a process using the `exit/2` function: `exit(Pid,Reason)`. In this case you do not have to add any code in your sensor module. If you use the atom `normal` as `Reason`, the process will die exactly as if is dying normally by itself.